# HttpResponse object error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting the error of **The view registration.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object.**

I am making an login app and I wants that when I click on login button the home page is shown to me.

When I am running view.py as given then I am getting the error of **Page not found localhost:8000/registration/home.html**

```
from django.template import  loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from registration.models import Registration
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext


def login(request):
    t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')

    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

The urls.py file is as:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index'),
        url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail'),
        url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'polls.views.results'),
        url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^registration/$', 'registration.views.login'),
```

and when I am try to run view.py as:

```
from django.template import  loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from registration.models import Registration
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

def login(request):
   t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')
   if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['user_name']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        # success
        return render_to_response(request,'registration/login.html')
```

then I am getting the error **The view registration.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object.**
The urls.py file remain same for this view.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load the template in each method; django will take care of that for you. Django requires that all methods that take are called from `urls.py` return a `HttpResponse` object.

Your method has lots of conditions where the return statement will never be reached. For example, what if the user is not active? What if request is not `POST`?

Try this version, which redirects the user back to the registration page if any of the conditions fail:

```
def login(request):
   # t = loader.get_template('registration/login.html') - not needed
   if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('user_name')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
      if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        # success
        return render(request,'registration/login.html')
      else:
        # user was not active
        return redirect('registration/')
    else:
        # not a valid user
        return redirect('registration/')
   else:
       # URL was accessed directly
       return redirect('registration/')
```

Comment: @Burhan, may I ask you to have a look at a related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671066/python-django-ajax-valueerror-the-view-khobor-views-show-recommendation-didn  ?

Answer (score 0):

sample auth

view.py

```
def loginto(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
           return render_to_response('index1.html')
        else:
           return render_to_response('error1.html')
        else:
        return render_to_response('error2.html') 
    else:
        return render_to_response('error2.html')
```

url.py

```
url(r'^login', 'mytests.views.loginto', name='loginto'),
```

login.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url loginto %}">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" /><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" /><br />
  <div align="center">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rakesh you are missing `{% csrf_token %}` in your form, and you need to return `RequestContext` from the view; that is why the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) is very handy.

Comment: @Rakesh, may I ask you to have a look  at a related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671066/python-django-ajax-valueerror-the-view-khobor-views-show-recommendation-didn ?