# python django ajax : ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x

I know such questions exist gallore in SO. But none satisfies my problem. My code however **works in localhost in my PC but not in online server**. The site is [here](http://amarkhobor.ml:8000/show_articles/). You can go to the `English` tab and click a news headline to see the ajax request.  It is a simple ajax request from the template to the `view.py` file through a URL defined in the `urls.py` file. The url (i.e. `show_recommendation`) is defined in the following way :

```
from django.contrib import admin
#from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from khobor import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^find_feed/', views.find_feed, name="find_feed"),
    url(r'^show_articles/', views.show_articles, name="show_articles"),
    url(r'^clear_cookie/', views.clear_cookie, name="clear_cookie"),
    url(r'^show_recommendation', views.show_recommendation, name="show_recommendation"),
    ]
```

JavaScript code in template is as follows:

```
       $.ajax({

                    url:"/show_recommendation/",
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                   data:{
                      id_found:id_found,
                      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'

                    },
                    success:function (data) {

                        //data=$.parseJSON(data);

                        alert(data);
                        if(window.console){

                            console.log(" response data =  ");
                            console.log(data);
                        }



                         if($.isArray(data)){


                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                            var id_found=data[i][0];

                            if(window.console){

                                console.log(" id found = "+id_found+" id found result = "+jQuery.inArray(id_found, ids_all));

                            }
                            if(jQuery.inArray(id_found, ids_all) ==-1){





                                ids_all.push(id_found);
                                new_ids.push(id_found);

                            if(window.console){

                                console.log(" id pushed = "+id_found);

                            }



                            //$("#recommendations").append('<li>'+data[i][0]+' ... '+data[i][1]+'</li>');
                            $("#recommendations").append('<li class="article_indiv  inline_block">' +
                                '<span class="top_image inline_block"  data-id="'+data[i][0]+'" ><img src="'+data[i][4]+'" alt="image"/>'+
                                '</span>' +
                                '<a class="link" data-id="'+data[i][0]+'" target="_blank"  href="'+data[i][2]+'" >'+data[i][3]+'</a>' +
                                 '</li>');

                             $(".top_image").imagefill();

                           /* $(".top_image").each(function(){

                                $elem = $(this);
                                var data_id =$elem.attr('data-id');
                                if(jQuery.inArray(data_id, new_ids) !=-1){

                                    $elem.imagefill();

                                }

                            });*/

                            }
                         } // end of for loop

                        Cookies.set('ids_all', ids_all);
                         }


                }


            });
```

In `view.py` I have :

```
def show_recommendation(request):

    # recommendations=['item1','item2']
    # json_list=json.dumps(recommendations)

    if request.method=="POST" and request.is_ajax():
        #print("u see this response ? ");
        #return HttpResponse("this is the response ")
        id_found = request.POST['id_found'];
        news_found=news.objects.get(id=id_found)
        content_found=news_found.content


        all_news = news.objects.exclude(id=id_found).order_by('-id').all()
        myList=[]


        for news_indiv in all_news:
            content=news_indiv.content
            id=news_indiv.id
            headline=news_indiv.headline
            url=news_indiv.url
            image=news_indiv.image
            result_similarity=cosine_sim(content,content_found)
            myList.append([id, result_similarity,url,headline,image])


        # myList = [3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 0, -5, 6, -7]
        # myList = [[12, .45633], [13, .245633], [14, .3323], [15, .8756]]

        result = quickSort(myList)
        total_rows = len(result)
        resultList=[]
        resultList.append(result[total_rows-1])
        resultList.append(result[total_rows-2])
        resultList.append(result[total_rows-3])
        #print("resultList === ")
        #print(resultList)

        json_list = json.dumps(resultList)

        #if(json_list is None):
        #   json_list="0";


        print ("before HttpResponse ")
        return HttpResponse(json_list)
        #return HttpResponse("dfdfdfdf")
        #return json_list
```

In my online server, I get the following error **though it works pretty fine in my localhost on my PC :**

```
Internal Server Error: /show_recommendation/

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers
/exception.py", line 35, in inner

    response = get_response(request)

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", 

line 139, in _get_response

    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)

ValueError: The view khobor.views.show_recommendation didn't return an 

HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

[03/Jun/2018 21:00:44] "POST /show_recommendation/ HTTP/1.1" 500 54424
```

**How to remove the error now ?**

Comment: Not only when you post on `show_recommendation(request):` you got error, but when access the view with GET method, there's no Http Response. think when the `request.method != 'POST'`, what's the response

Comment: @Lemayzeur, wrong files were uploaded in online server. See now online.

Comment: @Lemayzeur, I hit the url (http://amarkhobor.ml:8000/show_recommendation/) in web browser and got the error again.

Comment: You don't have any condition for handling 'GET' requests.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, ajax is making a `POST` request there. Why should I handle a `GET` request there ? Just for suppressing errors in `GET` request, I can handle that. But still it does not solve the error in ajax POST request .

Comment: Yes, I understand, but clicking the link you shared will not trigger a POST request for us. And hardly anyway to replicate an ajax with csrf and all.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, why won't it trigger any POST request ? The JS code defines the `method` as `POST`, right ?

Comment: The ajax POST request runs **asynchronously** from your page. Not by clicking on the url.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, to my surprise, it works now. The server did not act on the newly edited  files instantly, rather it took much time to recognize that a few files were updated- can it be any reason ?

Comment: `.pyc` files probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149832/where-are-the-pyc-files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172360/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-moses-koledoye).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the server is using `.pyc` files as pointed out in the comments.

Depending on how you are hosting the site, you will need to restart your Django Server process to trigger updates and recompilation of `.pyc` files.

For Gunicorn, this post discusses how to autoload on changes. [gunicorn autoreload on source change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change)

If you aren't using Gunicorn and post more about your server setup, I'll edit it this to match your use case.

Comment: my server uses CENT OS 7 . any instructions for that ?

Comment: Apache? Maybe `sudo systemctl restart httpd` and 
`sudo systemctl enable httpd`. I'm also seeing `sudo service apache2 graceful`